# Detecting invalid moves in Tic Tac Toe GUI java + quit button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have my code almost entirely working and just ran into a couple of small problems. For one, I want the user to receive a popup when they try to select a button already marked with an X or an O, telling them the move is invalid and to pick another. Secondly, I'm trying to add a quit button to the bottom of the game, but it always makes the quit button part of the game grid? The solution is probably simple and I'm just not seeing it, but I've tried it a couple different times and can't seem to get it out of that grid. Thanks for all help.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

class TicTacToeFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private int[][] winningMoves = new int[][]{
    {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9},
    {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 6, 9},
    {1, 5, 9}, {3, 5, 7}
};

private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
private JButton buttons[] = new JButton[10];
private JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
private int moveCount = 0;
private String letter = "";
private boolean win = false;
ActionListener quitListener = new quitListener();

public TicTacToeFrame() {
    JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
    bottom.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    quitButton.addActionListener(quitListener);
    bottom.add(quitButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        buttons[i] = new JButton();
        frame.add(buttons[i]);
        buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
    }

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        if (a.getSource() == buttons[i]) {
            buttons[i].setText("X");
            buttons[i].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    moveCount++;
    computer();

}

public void computer() {
    moveCount++;
    if (buttons[1].getText().equals("O") && buttons[2].getText().equals("O") && buttons[3].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[3].setText("O");
        buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[4].getText().equals("O") && buttons[5].getText().equals("O") && buttons[6].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[6].setText("O");
        buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[7].getText().equals("O") && buttons[8].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[9].setText("O");
        buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[2].getText().equals("O") && buttons[3].getText().equals("O") && buttons[1].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[1].setText("O");
        buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[5].getText().equals("O") && buttons[6].getText().equals("O") && buttons[4].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[4].setText("O");
        buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[8].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("O") && buttons[7].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[7].setText("O");
        buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[1].getText().equals("O") && buttons[3].getText().equals("O") && buttons[2].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[2].setText("O");
        buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[4].getText().equals("O") && buttons[6].getText().equals("O") && buttons[5].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[5].setText("O");
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[7].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("O") && buttons[8].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[8].setText("O");
        buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[1].getText().equals("O") && buttons[4].getText().equals("O") && buttons[7].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[7].setText("O");
        buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[2].getText().equals("O") && buttons[5].getText().equals("O") && buttons[8].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[4].setText("O");
        buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[3].getText().equals("O") && buttons[6].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[9].setText("O");
        buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[4].getText().equals("O") && buttons[7].getText().equals("O") && buttons[1].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[1].setText("O");
        buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[5].getText().equals("O") && buttons[8].getText().equals("O") && buttons[2].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[2].setText("O");
        buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[6].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("O") && buttons[3].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[3].setText("O");
        buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[1].getText().equals("O") && buttons[7].getText().equals("O") && buttons[4].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[4].setText("O");
        buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[2].getText().equals("O") && buttons[8].getText().equals("O") && buttons[5].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[5].setText("O");
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[3].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("O") && buttons[6].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[6].setText("O");
        buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[1].getText().equals("O") && buttons[5].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[9].setText("O");
        buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[5].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("O") && buttons[1].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[1].setText("O");
        buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[1].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("O") && buttons[5].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[5].setText("O");
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[3].getText().equals("O") && buttons[5].getText().equals("O") && buttons[7].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[7].setText("O");
        buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[7].getText().equals("O") && buttons[5].getText().equals("O") && buttons[3].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[3].setText("O");
        buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[7].getText().equals("O") && buttons[3].getText().equals("O") && buttons[5].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[5].setText("O");
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[1].getText().equals("X") && buttons[2].getText().equals("X") && buttons[3].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[3].setText("O");
        buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[4].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("X") && buttons[6].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[6].setText("O");
        buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[7].getText().equals("X") && buttons[8].getText().equals("X") && buttons[9].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[9].setText("O");
        buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[2].getText().equals("X") && buttons[3].getText().equals("X") && buttons[1].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[1].setText("O");
        buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[5].getText().equals("X") && buttons[6].getText().equals("X") && buttons[4].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[4].setText("O");
        buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[8].getText().equals("X") && buttons[9].getText().equals("X") && buttons[7].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[7].setText("O");
        buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[1].getText().equals("X") && buttons[3].getText().equals("X") && buttons[2].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[2].setText("O");
        buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[4].getText().equals("X") && buttons[6].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[5].setText("O");
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[7].getText().equals("X") && buttons[9].getText().equals("X") && buttons[8].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[8].setText("O");
        buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[1].getText().equals("X") && buttons[4].getText().equals("X") && buttons[7].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[7].setText("O");
        buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[2].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("X") && buttons[8].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[8].setText("O");
        buttons[8].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[3].getText().equals("X") && buttons[6].getText().equals("X") && buttons[9].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[9].setText("O");
        buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[4].getText().equals("X") && buttons[7].getText().equals("X") && buttons[1].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[1].setText("O");
        buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[5].getText().equals("X") && buttons[8].getText().equals("X") && buttons[2].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[2].setText("O");
        buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[6].getText().equals("X") && buttons[9].getText().equals("X") && buttons[3].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[3].setText("O");
        buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[1].getText().equals("X") && buttons[7].getText().equals("X") && buttons[4].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[4].setText("O");
        buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[2].getText().equals("X") && buttons[8].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[5].setText("O");
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[3].getText().equals("X") && buttons[9].getText().equals("X") && buttons[6].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[6].setText("O");
        buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[1].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("X") && buttons[9].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[9].setText("O");
        buttons[9].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[5].getText().equals("X") && buttons[9].getText().equals("X") && buttons[1].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[1].setText("O");
        buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[1].getText().equals("X") && buttons[9].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[5].setText("O");
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[3].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("X") && buttons[7].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[7].setText("O");
        buttons[7].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[7].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("X") && buttons[3].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[3].setText("O");
        buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[7].getText().equals("X") && buttons[3].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[5].setText("O");
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[1].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("O") && buttons[9].getText().equals("X")) {
        buttons[6].setText("O");
        buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[3].getText().equals("X") && buttons[5].getText().equals("O") && buttons[7].getText().equals("X")) {
        buttons[4].setText("O");
        buttons[4].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[5].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[5].setText("O");
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);
    } else if (buttons[1].getText().equals("")) {
        buttons[1].setText("O");
        buttons[1].setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        if (moveCount >= 9) {
            checkWinner();
        } else {
            random();
        }
    }

    checkWinner();

}

public void random() {
    Random x = new Random();
    int y = 1 + x.nextInt(9);
    if (buttons[y].getText().equals("O") || buttons[y].getText().equals("X")) {
        random();
    } else {
        buttons[y].setText("O");
        buttons[y].setEnabled(false);
    }
}

class quitListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    } 
}

public void checkWinner() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
        if (buttons[winningMoves[i][0]].getText().equals(buttons[winningMoves[i][1]].getText())
                && buttons[winningMoves[i][1]].getText().equals(buttons[winningMoves[i][2]].getText())
                && !buttons[winningMoves[i][0]].getText().equals("")) {
            win = true;
        }
    }

    if (moveCount % 2 == 0) {
        letter = "O";
    } else {
        letter = "X";
    }

    if (win == true) {
        int select = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, letter + " wins! Would you like to play again?");
        if(select == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) 
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) 
            {
            buttons[i].setText("");
            buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
            moveCount = 0;
            win = false;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if(select == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) 
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }    
        }
    }
    else if (moveCount >= 9 && win == false) 
    {
        int select = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "It's a tie! Would you like to play again?");
        if(select == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) 
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) 
            {
            buttons[i].setText("");
            buttons[i].setEnabled(true);
            moveCount = 0;
            win = false;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if(select == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) 
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }    
        }
    }
}
}
```

Runner:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TicTacToeRunner 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    JFrame frame = new TicTacToeFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: 1. Get rid of all that redundancy. Unnecessarily complex code is hard to debug code. 2. Separate your program logic (the logic underlying the tic-tac-toe game) from the GUI code. This too will make it easier to debug and enhance your game. 3. Ask a single specific question as yours appears to be a multi-parter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In your JButton's ActionListener, you can get the button that has been pressed via the ActionEvent's `getSource()` method. Simply call `getText()` on that JButton and if it holds the offending text, show an error JOptionPane. Or just use your `buttons[i]` variable within the loop, since it points to the offending JButton.
2. If you go this route, **be sure that the exit button has its own separate ActionListener**. Otherwise you may run into trouble. An inner anonymous class would work well here.
3. You've set the layout of the **entire** GUI, the JFrame, to be GridLayout, and this boxes you into a grid whether you like it or not. Don't do this. Leave the JFrame's contentPane to use its default BorderLayout, create a new JPanel for the tic tac toe grid, give it a GridLayout, add it to the JFrame BorderLayout.CENTER, and then add the bottom JPanel to the JFrame BorderLayout.PAGE_END.

---

Side recommendations unrelated to your questions:

- Get rid of all that redundancy. Unnecessarily complex code is hard to debug code.
- Separate your program logic (the logic underlying the tic-tac-toe game) from the GUI code. This too will make it easier to debug and enhance your game.
- In the future, strive to ask a single specific question as yours appears to be a multi-parter.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful; I'll go mess around with my code some more.